# 403 Error Permission Denied on BigQuery while trying to access table from custom container on vertexAI

Tags: python, google-bigquery, vertex, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-vertex-ai

We are trying to deploy a custom container on `vertexAI`, below you find the part where we call the `bigquery table` in our `python task` :

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from prophet import Prophet
from prophet.serialize import model_to_json, model_from_json
import os
import argparse
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import aiplatform

BUCKET_ROOT = '/gcs/ourbucket'
training_data_uri = 'myproject-id.poc_vertex.train_set'
project_id = "myproject-id" 
region = "europe-west1" 
aiplatform.init(project=project_id, location=region, staging_bucket=BUCKET_ROOT)


bq_client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)
table = bq_client.get_table(training_data_uri)
```

After pushing the image to `artifact registry` and then deploying the model on vertex, we get this error :

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery....access denied  Permission denied on table ....
```

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are seeing indicates that the service account identity you are using lacks sufficient access privilege to execute a query. To fix this exception, you must grant your service account identity required permissions by assigning it a “Reader” role or more on the project.